# Do I really need lithium batteries? (1.5 V, AA)

Tags: voltage, batteries

I just bought a [Skey indoor-outdoor weather station](https://www.amazon.de/SKEY-Wetterstation-Farbdisplay-Thermometer-Hygrometer-Hintergrundbeleuchtung/dp/B07KF4K35L/).

It comes with a separate outdoor sensor, connected to the indoor display unit by radio.  The outdoor unit needs 2 AA batteries and they specifically recommend lithium-ion ones because they work better in the cold.

But they are hard to find.  Mostly they are "photo" size batteries that won't fit in the battery compartment.  The one AA size I did find was 3.6 V (it said lithium but not lithium-ion).  I suppose I could slap one of those in, and jumper out the other side of the compartment; but that still leaves me 0.6 V over.

I rarely get colder than -7 °C 20°F here.  Do I really need lithium batteries?

Comment: You provide a link to a (German) Amazon article.  [You can buy the specified batteries on Amazon, as well.](https://www.amazon.de/Varta-Lithium-Batterie-Batterien-abweichen-Silber-Violett/dp/B004RPMHBE/ref=mp_s_a_1_5?keywords=1.5V+lithium+aa+battery&qid=1573820919&sr=8-5)  Looks like a reasonable (for Germany) price to me.

Comment: My question is not about *where* to buy the batteries.

Comment: "My question is not about where to buy the batteries." Except for the part where you said "But they are hard to find" when referring to the lithium batteries.   Also note that I didn't post it as an answer, but rather as a comment since the "hard to find" bit obviously wasn't the main thrust of your question.  If your question had simply been "where can I buy lithium batteries," I'd have voted to close instead of commenting.

Answer (score 3):

The page in German appears to NOT say what you claim.
Ich spreche ungefähr null deutsch :-(.
Google Übersetzer sagt:

- Use standard alkaline or lithium batteries for the outdoor sensor in cold weather. DO NOT use high performance batteries or rechargeable batteries.

And a User comment says

- The outdoor sensor requires for operation 2 AA batteries, preferably lithium variants, as they work better than the alkali variants in cold weather.  ...

**Lithium-Ion and "Lithium" are NOT the same.**

Lithium primary (non-rechargeable) cells are available in a number of chemistries and the ones they mention are a direct replacement for AA-Alkaline ones. They have a similar terminal voltage, higher energy content, flatter discharge curve, better low temperature operation and, usually, a much higher proce than Alkaline cells.
They are useful in niche applications where their special characteristics may be of value or ecen essential, but in most cases AA Alkaline cells work almost as well and are much better value for money.

In the case of your weather station and given the likely minimum temperature range I'd expect the Alkaline cells to be entirely acceptable. Usually.
eg after a long period of use if there was a much colder than usual day the Lithium cells may still operate whjen the Alkaline one would not.
But using Alkaline and replacing periodically will probably be cheaper overall and just as good.

---

Example of performance of Lithium AA cell.
Key areas noted in red or green.

Datasheet [Energiser L91 Lithium](https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/l91.pdf)
[Similar](https://cellpacksolutions.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/L91.pdf)

17 page datasheet & application manual [here](https://data.energizer.com/PDFs/lithiuml91l92_appman.pdf)

[image]
https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/l91.pdf

Comment: How flat is the discharge curve on those batteries? I know LiCl2 batteries have **too flat** curve and are banned in safety equipment since it's virtually impossible to detect low battery.

Comment: @JanDorniak See addition to my answer. A lovely battery. Shame about the cost. 20+ year shelf life.  At -40C hardly any loss of capacity at 25 mA discharge. Endpoint voltage of say 1.3V to 95%+ capacity at 1 to 100 mA. || Beats Alkaline into a cocked hat :-).

Comment: yup, that's true. But for IoT and similar non-critical uses LiCl2 has it bet in cost and the fact that a single cell is 3.6 V. They are getting more available too. Only loose out in low temperature usage.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use only regular AA non-rechargeable batteries (1.5 V nominal).

> Verwenden Sie bei kaltem Wetter Standard-Alkali- oder Lithiumbatterien für den Außensensor. KEINE Hochleistungsbatterien oder wiederaufladbare Batterien verwenden.

Higher voltage batteries such as lithium based battery (nominal 3.6-3.7 V) might definitely damage the unit.

Note, just as you stated, that discharging any type of battery in the cold will negatively impact its capacity, but the effect are much higher on alkaline.

From Energizer datasheet we can observe that for a 250mA discharge, you loose half the capacity in an alkaline at 0°C compared to its capacity at 20°C. Whereas for lithium-ion the capacity is barely affected by a change of temperature of 20°C to 0°C.

Source:

https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/alkaline_appman.pdf

https://data.energizer.com/PDFs/lithiuml91l92_appman.pdf

In your case the current cunsumption will be very small, also alkaline have a decent energy density. For your weather unit it should do the job fine.